# Private Ethereum blockchain does not sync last 65 block

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, synchronization

I've successfully create a private Ethereum network, I've two machines on the same local network, the first one is where I've created the chain, the second should be a new peer that should sync with the first one.
Everything works fine, addPeer correctly works and I can see the two nodes in the netowrk, but the second node when trying to sync the blockchain stuck at block 5574 of 5839.

As I can see online is a quite common problem, but I cannot find a solution regarding private ethereum network. I've already tried --syncmode fast but does not help.

EDIT:

I've tried to mine with the first node, and the second start to sync the blockchain again, but it stucks always at 65 blocks to the end.

This is what `eth.syncing` says every time:

```
{
  currentBlock: 5789,
  highestBlock: 5854,
  knownStates: 8,
  pulledStates: 8,
  startingBlock: 5789
}
```

Now the last node in my blockchain is 5854, but the second node stop syncing at 5789.

This is instead what loop in the console:

```
INFO [08-12|11:15:42.672] Imported new block headers               count=0 elapsed=6.452ms  number=5854 hash=776928…4288ca ignored=65
WARN [08-12|11:15:42.767] Node data write error                    err="state node a736c3…a6fb08 failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
WARN [08-12|11:15:42.842] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="state node a736c3…a6fb08 failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
```

Please help, I really cannot find a solution, thank you.

EDIT 2:

I suppose the the issue is in the genesis file. I've recreated the chain with a new genesis file, this is the old one:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 77,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x20",
    "gasLimit": "0x2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "8b06011b54a70f2a5a674a3bc24b81d0792dc941": 
         { "balance": "0x1337000000000000000000" }     
    }
}
```

This is the new one generated with puppeth:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 77,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "ethash": {}
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5b7000cc",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x80000",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000005": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000006": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000007": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000009": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000010": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000011": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000012": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000013": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000014": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000015": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000016": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000017": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000018": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000019": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000020": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000021": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000022": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000023": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000024": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000025": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000026": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000027": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000028": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000029": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000030": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000031": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000032": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000033": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000034": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000035": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000036": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000037": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000038": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000039": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000040": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000041": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000042": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000043": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000044": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000045": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000046": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000047": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000048": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000049": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000050": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000051": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000052": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000053": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000054": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000055": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000056": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000057": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000058": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000059": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000060": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000061": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000062": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000063": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000064": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000065": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000066": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000067": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000068": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000069": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000070": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000071": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000072": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000073": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000074": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000075": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000076": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000077": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000078": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000079": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000080": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000081": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000082": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000083": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000084": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000085": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000086": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000087": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000088": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000089": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000090": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000091": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000092": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000093": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000094": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000095": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000096": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000097": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000098": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000099": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000aa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ab": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ac": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ad": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ae": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000af": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ba": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000be": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ca": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ce": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000da": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000db": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000de": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000df": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ea": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000eb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ec": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ed": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ee": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ef": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fe": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ff": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "8b1266b8129a902f7d5bbc370054137cee34334c": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Every chain generated with first genesis file fails during sync across peers, but with the second one no. Anyone knows why?

Comment: it is not a common problem for a private chain at height 5k blocks to get stuck in syncing phase. you should complete this in less than a minute

Comment: if you start mining on the nodes, what happens ?

Comment: what is the output of `eth.syncing` ?

Comment: @Nulik I've edit the question with info you request

Comment: do eth.getBlock(0) on both nodes, and check the `Hash` field, it must be the same for both nodes

Comment: you must not  have different genesis file on the nodes

Comment: the nodes don't sync because the last process of syncing trie can't be completed, for some uknown reason. Try to do a full sync `--gcmode archive` and `--syncmode full` on the node that is being connected

Comment: `eth.getBlock(0)` return the same hash value on both nodes, but even with `--gcmode archive` and  `--syncmode full` the second node has the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the genesis file. In the first genesis json I've not specified the `extraData` field. This cause that the first block of the chain has a strange value in its `extraData` field.

Here is what happens if in the genesis json there isn't:

```
{
  difficulty: 32,
  extraData: "0x",
  gasLimit: 34603008,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0x2066362553ef96616831d4cd2b5d83a094c8a8d5a72075c54b2533adf9b7f0cf",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
  number: 0,
  parentHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 537,
  stateRoot: "0x628cb5c97b5614e02d6fda3b0684f7464cb933c4cb5e09e2d74b56963db036d4",
  timestamp: 0,
  totalDifficulty: 32,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

**0x** is not a number. This cause the issue, because if I add this line in the genesis file:

```
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
```

The syncing problem disappear.